# use grep in an if statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, grep

Im a beginner in shell scripting needing a script to check the status of a process and give me the output 'running' when up and 'not running' when down.

I tried the below one, but it did not work:

```
if [ -s `/opt/reds/recycle.sh status | grep "pid"` ];
then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: `if [ -s $(/opt/reds/recycle.sh status | grep "pid") ];`

Comment: Classically, the `-s` operation checks whether the file named by the following argument has a non-zero size (is not an empty file).  What are you trying to do with `-s`?

Answer (score 5):

Change the `if` statement to:

```
if /opt/reds/recycle.sh status | grep "pid"
then
    ...
fi
```

You might want to silent grep:

`-q` for quiet operation.
`-s` to suppress error messages (It's not needed here, as `grep` is taking input from `stdin`).

In general, to check for exit status of a command with `if`:

```
if command;then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Though you'll want to add a `-q` flag to `grep` to avoid having the matches printed to standard output.

Comment: @tripleee yap, there's also a `-s` option to suppress error message

Comment: Indeed; though I have a hard time imagining what sort of error messages you could expect from reading standard input, and still want to ignore.  If the machine runs out of memory or something like that, you probably do want to be notified.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, right.. It's not needed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If the `recycle.sh` script is at all correctly implemented, it should set its exit code to indicate the status.

If that is the case, you should be able to observe that it returns zero when the status is okay (meaning, presumably, that the service is running) and non-zero otherwise.

Then, you won't need `grep` at all.

```
if /opt/reds/recycle.sh status >/dev/null; then
    echo running
else
    echo not running
fi
```

A correctly written script might also have a `--query` option or similar (`--quiet`, `--silent`, `--script`?) which allows for its use in this construct without redirecting its output.

Comment: Thank you. It worked :-)  But, the recycle.sh has some errors though because of which some unnecessary lines are appearing the output. How to get only 'running' or 'not running' in the output ?

Comment: The redirection to `/dev/null` should already get rid of any normal output.  If it also prints spurious output to standard error, you'll need to add `2>&1` to the redirection.

Comment: I tried that actually. I get the same error..

"if /opt/reds/recycle.sh status 2>&1>/dev/null;"

Comment: No, that's `>/dev/null 2>&1;`

Comment: Sorry for bugging you @tripleee.. I tried this one as well with no luck. The recycle.sh writes some error in the output when the process is not running. this actually is perfectly fine. But, doesn't look good to see in the output of my 'find the status' script. :(

Comment: If the output is written to the TTY by force, I don't see how to work around it.  Perhaps you could post a separate question with the pertinent snippet out of the status script for advice on how to fix it.